# Pandas - drop first column and add index

Tags: python, pandas

Doing:

```
# extract data
df = pd.read_csv('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/total_cases.csv')
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
#transpose columns to rows
df = df.T
# swap all NAN with 0.0
df = df.fillna(0.0)
```

I have:

```
date         2020-04-20  2020-04-21  
World        2355853.0   2431890.0  
Afghanistan  996.0      1031.0  
Albania      562.0       584.0  
Algeria      2629.0      2718.0
```

Now I wish to drop the first column create an index, ending up with:

```
    2020-04-20  2020-04-21  
0   2355853.0   2431890.0  
1   996.0       1031.0  
2   562.0       584.0  
3   2629.0      2718.0
```

How?

Edit:

```
date  2019-12-31  2020-01-01  2020-01-02  2020-01-03  2020-01-04  2020-01-05  \
0           27.0        27.0        27.0        44.0        44.0        59.0   
1            0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
2            0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
```

Comment: How about ```df.reset_index(drop=True)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.reset_index().drop('date', axis=1)
```

OR

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: same thing. not found in axis

Comment: name 'date' still is there, though. can it be removed?

Comment: `date` is your dataframe's index or a normal column?

Comment: it's index, it was set, please refer to question, at the top

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `df.reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: Did you re-assign my command to the `df`. Like, `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`? If you did and `date` still appears in index, please do `del df.index.name`.